# Why font-face doesn't work in my project?

Tags: css, sass, font-face, laravel-mix

I'm tryin' to change font-family in a laravel-mix project, but this code doesn't work.
Any help?
Thanks!!

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    src: url(../font/Montserrat-Bold.ttf);
}

body {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `format('truetype')`, like this: `src: url(../font/Montserrat-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');`?

Comment: I tried both solution, but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

please try. do with ttc, not ttf. if don't have no ttf, then use online convert tool.

```
@font-face {   font-family: yourFontName;   font-weight: normal;   src: url('./asset/fonts/meiryo.ttc') format('TTC'); } @font-face {   font-family: yourFontName;   font-weight: bold;   src: url('./asset/fonts/meiryob.ttc') format('TTC'); } body{   font-family: yourFontName;   font-size: 25px; }
```

Comment: I tried both solution, but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please check this again. jhon sammie